# forEach seems to be working for push() function but didn't work for pop() in JavaScript. can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
     //code1
     let a= [1, 3 , 4, 6];
     [7, 8 , 9].forEach(l => a.push(l));
     console.log(a);
     // [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

1.it worked for push() function

---

```
     //code2
     let a= [1, 3 , 4, 6];
     a.forEach(l => a.pop(l));

     console.log(a);
     //[ 1, 3 ]
```

2.    didn't work for pop() though

Comment: Go and read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) first.

Comment: The title should give a summary of the problem and not contain the complete question...

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `Array.pop()` removes the last element from the array and returns that.

Example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
arr.pop(); // returns 3
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

If you want to remove a element with specific value than try something like:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var index = arr.indexOf(1);
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(arr.pop());

var index = arr.indexOf(2);
if (index > -1) {
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Can u suggest how i can use forEach for pop() or for removing all the elements of the array.

Comment: @sahil you can use Array.splice and forEach to remove all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

### forEach automatically extracts the elements one by one and gives them to you

It starts from the **beginning** of the array, and does them **all**.

It **doesn't delete** elements from the array.

```js
a = [1, 3, 4, 6];
a.forEach(item => console.log(item));

// output is in forwards order
// and 'a' retains original contents
```

### pop() extracts and deletes one element for you

It starts from the **end** of the array, and does **only one**.

It **deletes** the element from the array.

```js
a = [1, 3, 4, 6];
while (a.length > 0) {
  console.log(a.pop())
}

// items come out in reverse order
// and 'a' is being emptied so it is [] at the end
```

### Choose your method

Do you want the last element actually removed from the array? This is what you would want if you were implementing a stack, for example. In that case, use ".pop()".

This gets **one** element from the **end** of the array and **deletes** it from the array.

Or do you want to just look at **each** element in turn from the array (starting at the **beginning**), **without** changing the array itself. This is a commoner situation. In this case, use ".forEach"